# Parsing Json with Promise in Tableau

Tags: javascript, json, tableau-api

I'm working on tableau and I have to build my own web data connector.
I wrote it and it works perfectly on Chrome.
But when I use it into Tableau I get the foolowing error :

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Promise file: http://localhost:9000/json-connector line: 246
```

My connector is devided in two parts. The first part call a web service to get a list of destinations and fill two lists with their names. The second part call another web service to get every paths beetween two selected destinations.

The error occured while I want to get the first list. I want to insist that it works on chrome, but not in tableau.

The portion of code where the error occured :

```
var getJSON = function(url) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('get', url, true);
    xhr.responseType = 'json';
    xhr.onload = function() {
      var status = xhr.status;
      if (status == 200) {
        resolve(xhr.response);
      } else {
        console.log("Something went wrong with the destination")
        reject(status);
      }
    };
    xhr.send();
  });
};
```

I think that tableau doesn't support Promise. But I don't know how to make a work around. Thank's a lot for your help !

This is how I use this function :

```
getJSON('http://localhost:9000/stations').then(function(data) {
    //alert('Your Json result is:  ' + data.result); //you can comment this, i used it to debug
    //result.innerText = JSON.stringify(data); //display the result in an HTML element

    console.log("starting parsing on : " + data.length);
    var listArrival = document.getElementById('Arrival'); //get the list where you want to add options
    var listDeparture = document.getElementById('Departure');
    if(listArrival == null || listDeparture == null) console.error("Impossible to retrieve the list")
    var op;
    var addedStations = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < data.length ; i++){   
        var obj = data[i];  
        var overflowControler = 0;   
        for(var key in obj){
            console.log(key + '=' + obj[key]);
            if(key == 'name' && addedStations.indexOf(obj[key]) == -1){  
                op = new Option(obj[key], obj['nlc'], true);
                op2 = new Option(obj[key], obj['nlc'], true);
                if(op == null) console.error("Impossible to create the new option")
                listArrival.add(op);
                listDeparture.add(op2);
                addedStations.push(obj[key]);
            }
            overflowControler ++; 
            if(overflowControler > maxLengthOfEachRecordFromJson) break; // overflow control
        }
        if(i > maxStationsRecordNumberFromJson) break; //overflow control
    }

}, function(status) { //error detection....
  alert('Something went wrong.');
});
```

Comment: Can you include an external Promise library into your tableau project (if that's the correct name, I don't know a lot about tableau)?

Comment: I can include some library in my js yes !
exemple : <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://connectors.tableau.com/libs/tableauwdc-1.1.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: Then include one of those: https://cdnjs.com/#q=promise - I'd go for `bluebird`, but if all you need is basic ES6 promises, the more lightweight `es6-promise` will do.

Comment: I'll give it a try !

Comment: Thank you a lot ! I don't have the error anymore !
But my lists are empty.. Same code works perfectly on chrome..

Comment: Difficult to say. You will have to test which line fails yourself, I'm afraid I can't help you much there. (That being said, if the only place where you use promises is that `getJSON` function, then you don't really need to use promises at all. That function can be written without using them.)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried it on the Tableau Simulator and it's work. So it's a problem with some cross-domain connection now.. Thank you !
can close this.

Comment: You're welcome. You can write up a short answer that shows the procedure of adding a promise library to Tableau. This might help others who run into this question through a search - and it gives you a way of closing this thread by accepting your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by Tomalak I added a library to my script and Tableau is able to use Promise.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es6-promise/3.2.1/es6-promise.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I didn't make other changes in the code.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately the browser used internally by Tableau (Qt 5.4 webkit) doesn't yet natively support Promises.  So this is the way to go for now.